# Combine 2 SQL Queries using Inner or Cross Join?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Trying to combine results from both queries

```
--#90 QUERY BEGIN

--012 WO MANH HOURS BY EMPLOYEE

select a.team_code, a.job_function_name, a.login_user_id, b.user_first_name, b.user_last_name, a.START_DATE_TIME, a.END_DATE_TIME, round((sum(case when level_5 = 'WORK ORDER' then total_time/60 - unpaid_brk/60 else 0 end)),2) as "HOURS"
from lm2015prd.e_consol_perf_smry a, lm2015prd.ucl_user b
where a.login_user_id = b.user_name
and a.level_5 = 'WORK ORDER'
and a.whse = '012'
and a.clock_in_status < 90
and a.team_code in ('PREKIT 1ST 08')
and a.clock_in_date > '2016-07-12 04:00' and a.clock_in_date < '2016-07-14 03:00'
group by a.team_code, a.job_function_name, a.login_user_id, b.user_first_name,
b.user_last_name, a.START_DATE_TIME, a.END_DATE_TIME
Order by a.LOGIN_USER_ID;

SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, round((sum(case when level_5 = 'WORK ORDER' then total_time/60 - unpaid_brk/60 else 0 end)),2) as "HOURS"
from lm2015prd.e_consol_perf_smry a, lm2015prd.ucl_user b
where a.login_user_id = b.user_name
and a.level_5 = 'WORK ORDER'
and a.whse = '012'
and a.clock_in_status < 90
and a.team_code in ('PREKIT 1ST 08')
and a.clock_in_date > '2016-07-13 04:00' and a.clock_in_date < '2016-07-14 03:00';
--QUERY END
```

Trying to combine both of these queries for 1 detailed result with grand totals

Comment: Look at [`ROLLUP`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets#rollup).

Comment: Since you already have them written out and nulls already placed for the irrelevant fields in the second query, you should just be able to remove the `;` after the `ORDER BY` and `UNION` the two queries. You also may want/need to tweak the order by after doing so.

Comment: Hi, When I remove the semi colon I get this error:

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 15 Column: 1

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned union is what your after

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp